# Problems building rust-http in rust-openssl

Tags: rust

According to cargo/rust when I try to build using rust-http I get an error in openssl.

```
Caused by:
  Process didn't exit successfully: `rustc src/lib.rs --crate-name openssl --crate-type lib -C metadata=fbe75530f7eda428 -C extra-filename=-fbe75530f7eda428 --out-dir /Users/cmp/Code/tmp/rustymud/target/deps --dep-info /Users/cmp/Code/tmp/rustymud/target/.fingerprint/openssl-fbe75530f7eda428/dep-lib-openssl -L /Users/cmp/Code/tmp/rustymud/target/deps -L /Users/cmp/Code/tmp/rustymud/target/deps` (status=101)
--- stderr
src/ssl/mod.rs:153:19: 153:32 error: unresolved name `ptr::null_mut`.
src/ssl/mod.rs:153         if ctx == ptr::null_mut() {
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl/mod.rs:354:19: 354:32 error: unresolved name `ptr::null_mut`.
src/ssl/mod.rs:354         if ssl == ptr::null_mut() {
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl/mod.rs:360:20: 360:33 error: unresolved name `ptr::null_mut`.
src/ssl/mod.rs:360         if rbio == ptr::null_mut() {
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl/mod.rs:365:20: 365:33 error: unresolved name `ptr::null_mut`.
src/ssl/mod.rs:365         if wbio == ptr::null_mut() {
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/crypto/hash.rs:99:57: 99:70 error: unresolved name `ptr::null_mut`.
src/crypto/hash.rs:99             EVP_DigestFinal(self.ctx, res.as_mut_ptr(), ptr::null_mut());
                                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/crypto/pkey.rs:110:23: 110:36 error: unresolved name `ptr::null_mut`.
src/crypto/pkey.rs:110             let rsa = ptr::null_mut();
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 6 previous errors
```

However, the rust documentation says that `ptr` is fine. The rust-openssl project has 'build success' o it's page. I have openssl 1.0.1i installed. I have a nightly version of rust (rustc 0.12.0-pre-nightly (2e92c67dc 2014-08-28 23:56:20 +0000))

What could be causing this problem and how do I solve it? Were there changes to rust that the docs haven't reflected? Do projects build only against the latest nightly and should I update to get a working build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your build of Rust is too old—it’s from several weeks ago. Upgrade your Rust.

Comment: I love when few weeks is too old.